# Как соединить две таблицы в SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, join, where

У меня есть две таблицы
Таблица 1. Должности с их зарплатой имеет вид:

| Должность | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SPE-A | 100 | 120 | 130 | 140 |
| SPE-B | 200 | 220 | 230 | 240 |

Таблица 2.

| Имя | должность | кат |
| --- | --- | --- |
| О. Петров | SPE-B | 2 |
| И. Иванов | SPE-A | 4 |

В итоге, хотелось бы видеть такой результат:

| Имя | должность | кат | оплата |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| О. Петров | SPE-B | 2 | 220 |
| И. Иванов | SPE-A | 4 | 140 |

Comment: Нормализуйте структуру хранения. Ну или пишите длинный CASE.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так (Sqlite):

```
select p.[Имя],p.[Должность],p.[кат]
  ,case when p.[кат]=1 then s.[1]
        when p.[кат]=2 then s.[2]
        when p.[кат]=3 then s.[3]
        when p.[кат]=4 then s.[4]
   else null
   end [оплата]
from person p
left join table1 s on s.[Должность]=p.[Должность]
```

Посмотрите пример для SQL Server с UNPIVOT:

```
with PositionSalary as(
SELECT [Должность], [кат],[оплата]
FROM   
   (SELECT [Должность],[1],[2],[3],[4]
   FROM table1) p  
UNPIVOT  
   ([оплата] FOR [кат] IN   
      ([1],[2],[3],[4])  
   )AS unpvt
)
select [Имя],p.[Должность],p.[кат],[Оплата] 
from person p
inner join positionSalary s 
  on p.[Должность]=s.[Должность] 
   and p.[кат]=s.[кат]
  ;
```

Comment: У меня  на sqlite всё сделано, работает ли unpivot в sqlite

Comment: unpivot в sqlite - думаю, нет. Вам подойдет 1-й пример. Точно работает в sqlite.